# Add Class to ALL Child of UL element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class

Well, I wanted to add class to all of li's of my ul, yet I don't know why it won't work.

My **CSS code**:

```
.vnav-menu li.selected {
    background:#fff;
}
```

here's my **html code** for it.

```
<ul class="vnav-menu">  <!-- Initiates Showing/Hiding Dashboard Containers -->
    <li onclick="vnav_function('current_offer');"   id="current_offer_li"   class="selected">   <a> CURRENT OFFERS  </a></li>
    <li onclick="vnav_function('draft_offer');"     id="draft_offer_li">                        <a> DRAFT OFFERS    </a></li>
    <li onclick="vnav_function('expired_offer');"   id="expired_offer_li">                      <a> EXPIRED OFFERS  </a></li>
    <li onclick="vnav_function('offer_code');"      id="offer_code_li">                         <a> OFFER CODE      </a></li>
    <li onclick="vnav_function('title');"           id="title_li">                              <a> TITLE           </a></li>
    <li onclick="vnav_function('schedule');"        id="schedule_li">                           <a> SCHEDULE        </a></li>
    <li onclick="vnav_function('offer_type');"      id="offer_type_li">                         <a> OFFER TYPE      </a></li>
</ul>
```

And here is my code for the function **vnav_function()**

```
function vnav_function(data) {  //Showing/Hiding Dashboard Containers
    $('.vnav-menu li').each(function(i)
    {
       $(this).attr('id').addClass("selected");
    });
}
```

Well, for some reason it won't work though. any ideas for this stuff?

Comment: What is `$(this).attr('id').addClass("selected");` supposed to do?

Comment: $(this).attr('id') <-- List of all LI id's so, I'm trying to add class with it

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `$(this).attr('id')` returns a string. What are you adding a class to?

Comment: Ohh, yeah after reading Asad's post, I'm returning a string, never knew that my bad. Thanks anyways and for spending ur time with this stuff. Solved by using Asad's answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to invoke the `addClass` method on the string returned by `$(this).attr('id')`. Try using the addClass method on the jQuery collection returned by `$(this)`:

```
$(this).addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

`.attr('id')` returns a string.  I think that you want to use the ID for comparison:

```
if ($(this).attr('id') == $(data.target).attr('id') {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

However, it would be much easier to just do

```
function vnav_function(data) {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
}
```

...and it would be *even* easier to do

```
<ul class="vnav-menu">  <!-- Initiates Showing/Hiding Dashboard Containers -->
    <li id="current_offer_li"   class="selected">   <a> CURRENT OFFERS  </a></li>
    <li id="draft_offer_li">                        <a> DRAFT OFFERS    </a></li>
    <li id="expired_offer_li">                      <a> EXPIRED OFFERS  </a></li>
    <li id="offer_code_li">                         <a> OFFER CODE      </a></li>
    <li id="title_li">                              <a> TITLE           </a></li>
    <li id="schedule_li">                           <a> SCHEDULE        </a></li>
    <li id="offer_type_li">                         <a> OFFER TYPE      </a></li>
</ul>

$(".vnav-menu li").on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

You may even want to do:

```
$(".vnav-menu li").on('click', function () {
    $(".vnav-menu").removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery:

```
function getElementsByCSSSelector(s) {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(s));
}

getElementsByCSSSelector('.vnav-menu li').forEach(function(li) {
    li.classList.add("selected");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function vnav_function(data) {  //Showing/Hiding Dashboard Containers
  $('.vnav-menu li').each(function()
  {
     $(this).addClass("selected");
  });
 }
```

Or just:

```
function vnav_function(data) {  //Showing/Hiding Dashboard Containers
   $('.vnav-menu li').addClass('extra');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well no need to use `.each` instead `$('.vnav-menu li').addClass('extra');` this can add `class` to every `li` inside `ul.vnav-menu`